# How to convert a Mesh into a Heightmap

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, mesh, vertices, procedural-generation

I am using unity for a project where my algorithm procedurally generates different kinds of terrains.

The problem is that, I am trying to add colors by adding textures to my mesh. I know how to do it which is by making a simple Heightmap and then some if-else logic.

But I can't really figure out the **algorithm** I need to use to convert a **mesh's vertex's y axis** to a **heightmap**.

so, does anyone know the Algorithm's name?

Comment: Why not add the texture directly to the mesh? Converting to a height map seems like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: A little bit unclear what your underlying goal is .. I think the easiest would actually be to use a shader that colors the object based on vertex height in the world .. then you wouldn't need to care about a texture at all .. e.g. like [this one](https://answers.unity.com/questions/882134/shader-based-on-vertex-height.html)